# How to require with Browserify?

Tags: javascript

I have a file `login.js` with a simple test function:

```
function login(username, password){

    console.log(Parse.User.currentUser())

}
```

I can't do `require('parse');` in that `login.js` file.

I have browserify setup, and have a file called `main.js` with `var Parse = require('parse');`

But i still get an error in the browser console when calling the function that `Parse` is not defined.

Comment: This needs more information. Please show us how you setup Browserify

Comment: I ran this: `browserify main.js -o bundle.js` and then `<script src="../scripts/bundle.js" charset="utf-8" type-></script>` in my html file.